# Как работает система классов-конструкторов и их прототипирование?

Tags: javascript, классы

сижу читаю книгу и пишу простенькие программы . Хочу понять как работает система классов в JS . Вроде бы прочитал две главы, просмотрел код , а понятней не стало . Вот код -

```
class Game {
        constructor(first, second) {
            this.person = first;
            this.friend = second;
        }
        consoleLog() {
            return this.friend + " " + this.person;
        }
    }

    class Attack extends Game {
        constructor(person, friend, fHealth, sHealth) {
            super(person, friend);
            this.personHealth = fHealth;
            this.friendHealth = sHealth;
        }
        allConsoleLog() {
            console.log(super.consoleLog() + " " + this.fHealth + " " + this.sHealth);
        }
    }
    let game = new Game("Jack", "Alex");
    let attack = new Attack(5, 8);
    attack.allConsoleLog();
```

По идеи , я должен ввести два аргумента в класс Game , потом два в класс Attack . Класс Attack должен перехватить их *прототипированием*, и вывести в консоль через функцию, но место вывода - (**Alex Jack 5 8**) , выводится - (**8 5 undefined undefined**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вглядитесь в порядок передачи параметров в базовый конструктор и в значения свойств созданных объектов.

```js
class Game {
  constructor(first, second) {
    this.person = first;
    this.friend = second;
  }
  consoleLog() {
    return this.friend + " " + this.person;
  }
}

class Attack extends Game {
  constructor(person, friend, fHealth, sHealth) {
    super(person, friend);
    this.personHealth = fHealth;
    this.friendHealth = sHealth;
  }
  allConsoleLog() {
    console.log(super.consoleLog() + " " + this.fHealth + " " + this.sHealth);
  }
}
let game = new Game("Jack", "Alex");
let attack = new Attack(5, 8); // where are the names?

console.log("game =", game);
console.log("attack =", attack);
```

Comment: Да, все работает, теперь знаю как смотреть свойства и объект класса. Почитал про super , и как работает конструктор , теперь все наследуется и работает. Можно еще спросить , чем полезны классы , кроме их-него якобы прототипирования ?

Comment: @mbfilipp Как и вообще в ООП - инкапсуляция и code reuse.